# segmentation fault at the end of the destructor on deleting integer pointer

Tags: c++, destructor

I am trying to understand the below program . While executing am getting errors as shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    int *a;
    int a1;
    int b;


    Base(){
        cout<<"Inside Constructor"<<endl;
        a1 = 10;
        a = &a1;
        cout<<"   "<<a<<endl;
        b = 20;
    }

    Base(const Base &rhs)
    {
        cout<<"Inside Copy Constructor"<<endl;
        a = new int;
        *a = *(rhs.a);
        b = rhs.b;
    }

    ~Base(void)
    {
    cout<<"Inside destructor"<<endl;
    delete a;
    }
};


int main()
{
Base obj;
Base obj2(obj);
cout<<"obj a "<<*(obj.a)<<" b "<<obj.b<<endl;
cout<<"obj2 a "<<*(obj2.a)<<" b "<<obj2.b<<endl;
obj.a1 = 30;
obj.b = 40;
cout<<"obj a "<<*(obj.a)<<" b "<<obj.b<<endl;
cout<<"obj2 a "<<*(obj2.a)<<" b "<<obj2.b<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

While executing this code i am getting the following output

```
Inside Constructor
Inside Copy Constructor
obj a 10 b 20
obj2 a 10 b 20
obj a 30 b 40
obj2 a 10 b 20
Inside destructor
Inside destructor
Segmentation fault
```

[EDIT]
I was looking for a way to destruct the heap memory that i have created in copy constructor . So what can be done here ? please suggest

[EDIT]

Comment: you are trying to ``delete`` something that you don't own: you only own the integer when you have done the ``new``. You can't expect to take an outside pointer and then destroy it in the destructor. What do you plan to achieve? Why are you using pointers? Avoid them :)

Comment: Thank you , I was looking for a way to destruct the heap memory that i have created in copy constructor . So what can be done here ? please suggest

Comment: I post an answer. I am assuming that you are using something more complex than an ``int``, and your answer consists in a minimal example of your problem. Is it so? Because in your example, is trivial to avoid using a ``new`` in order to achieve same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

delete should be used on memory allocated from heap using new only.

```
a1 = 10;
a = &a1;
```

In your case "a" is holding the address of memory in stack. So, you shouldn't call delete on that memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete memory acquired with `new` (dynamically allocated), not to an automatic-storage variable.

Answer (score 0):

In copy constructor you are using **new operator** to assign the memory for pointer **a** ,so u can delete it.But since u are not using **new operator** in default constructor, you can delete the pointer **a** .
You must use delete opearator to free the memory of variable which is in heap not in stack.

when you use **new operator** ,the variable is created in **heap** where as local variable are created in **stack** memory which can't be delete using **delete operator**

Comment: Thank you , I was looking for a way to destruct the heap memory that i have created in copy constructor . So what can be done here ? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the copy constructor, the problem is that you don't consistently use `new` (if you used move then maybe you would have a point). You have some options. I am trying to be useful, not exhaustive, maybe I'm missing other good design ideas.

#### Use `new` always (and consistently)

You can put a new in all the constructors, and thus, the destructor would always be able to call to `delete`. Even when you don't need it. It may be a ugly hack, but is consistent.

#### Never use `new`

If you never use `new`, you don't use `delete` either and the compiler ensures consistency and ensures that you don't mess up. Normally, you can rely on the compiler default behaviour on constructors.

#### Use smart pointers

If instead of calling to `delete` manually you save the variable inside a `unique_ptr`, then it will be deallocated at the destructor automatically by the compiler. The smart pointer is smart enough to know if it is initialized.

Beware that using a smart pointer means that you should never call `delete`, because if you do so without warning the smart pointer, you will stumble onto the same problem. If you are not familiarized with them and you are using C++11, it is a nice thing to learn :)

#### Track the status of your pointers

I would not vouch for this. It seems very `C` and not `C++`. However, you can always track a `bool` value and at destroy time check it. This is just like using smart pointers, but with an in-house implementation. I think that it is a bad design idea, although educational in some cases.